# How to upload 6Mb attachment in a custom Apex Rest service (heap size issue)

Tags: attachment, upload, file-storage

I have a .Net app, which works with SFDC via REST API. Not so long time ago we faced with big files. Usually they were around 2-3 Mb and it was OK for both .Net app and SFDC. Now there are some changes in app, which generate those files (file is archive which contains a number of files, the big part of the archive is a png file).
As I can see from documentation, neither SOAP API, nor REST API allow me to create an Attachment with size more than 5 Mb.
This Attachment is linked to a custom object.
Is there any way to upload or create smth to attach file to an object? Maybe through Email attachments. They allow to attach 25 Mb.
Maybe upload somehow asynchronously? But how?

Comment: Have you checked the API version being used when you try with SOAP and REST?

Comment: I always use (current version)-1

Comment: I'm in progress of writing a desktop app to test REST and SOAP APIs for Attachment object.

Answer (score 2):

With Summer '14 release, file size limits for attachments were increased to 25MB, so you should be fine:

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-gb/summer14/release-notes/rn_general_attachment_size_increase.htm

Comment: Yes, it's true. But I'm looking for a way to attach a file to an object via something, and not manually via web interface. I want .Net app to send somehow this file to SFDC.

Comment: the attachment size limit is at the attachment level, not the API, so if the limit has been increased them it should also apply to the API calls as well.

Comment: Use the script on this blog to bypass the limit http://kevansfdc.blogspot.com/2017/05/upload-attachment-to-salesforce-without.html

Answer (score 2):

I assume my question was not very accurate. The problem was that we use custom REST API. And the problem was in Heap Size in our code.

After I tried 'standard' Force.com REST API for Attachment object I was able to upload 24 MB file to my custom object.

Comment: Hi can you say a little more about how you did this?  I see this in the API docs: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm 
but that's about Documents, don't see anything in there specifically about uploading attachments.

Comment: https://xxx.salesforce.com/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Attachment/  post a proper body, and you will have your attachment inserted. https://xxx.salesforce.com/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Attachment/describe/

Comment: http://www.wadewegner.com/2014/05/uploading-an-attachment-to-salesforce-with-the-soap-and-rest-apis/